# Problem with regular expression lookbehinds in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to retrieve via regexp javascript figures

- 1 - preceded by either:

  - And | or
  - nothing
- 2 - followed by either:

  - Nothing
  - And | or

I thought of using lookbehind but it seems that javascript does not support lookbehind

thank you for helping me

Comment: Are all the symbols correctly posted? Isn't something missing here? What is the important thing here "And", "|", "or", "And | or"...?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is slightly confusing. By "nothing" do you mean anything, a space, or the beginning/end of the text? I'm assuming a space.

Although look-behind would be useful, it's not strictly necessary. Couldn't you just match the whole pattern?

```
document.body.innerHTML.search(/(and|or)? 1/);
document.body.innerHTML.search(/2 (and|or)?/);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do really need lookbehind, this might get you started: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript (and there's tons of other great stuff on there for Javascript regex, including his library, `XRegExp`).